# Laravel transient queues and messages

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

I'm working on Laravel 5.1.46 (LTS) with rabbitmq for message queues with [package](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq)

**.env**

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=rabbitmq
```

**config/queue.php**

```
'rabbitmq' => [
        'driver' => 'rabbitmq',

        'host' => env('RABBITMQ_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('RABBITMQ_PORT', 5672),

        'vhost' => env('RABBITMQ_VHOST', '/'),
        'login' => env('RABBITMQ_LOGIN', 'guest'),
        'password' => env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD', 'guest'),

        // name of the default queue,
        'queue' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE'),

        // create the exchange if not exists
        'exchange_declare' => true,

        // create the queue if not exists and bind to the exchange
        'queue_declare_bind' => true,

        'queue_params' => [
            'passive' => false,
            'durable' => true,  // false
            'exclusive' => false,
            'auto_delete' => false,
        ],

        'exchange_params' => [

            // more info at http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html
            'type' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_TYPE', 'direct'),

            'passive' => false,

            // the exchange will survive server restarts
            'durable' => true,  // fakse

            'auto_delete' => false,
        ]
```

I've **8** queues in total. Queue names are stored in **.env** file.

```
QUEUE_ONE=queue-one
QUEUE_TWO=queue-two
.
.
.
QUEUE_EIGHT=queue-eight
```

And while dispatching a job,

```
dispatch(new Job1())->onQueue(env('QUEUE_ONE'))
```

Queues and messages are persistent/durable.

Due to some performance issues, I need to change the durability of some queues and their messages. So,

- 5 queues and their messages will be transient (non-persistent)
- 3 queues and their messages will be persistent

How it is possible with-in Laravel and rabbitmq ?

Note :
I know, I can set

```
durable = false
```

but it will be for all queues,

Comment: The config you shared only defines 1 queue though.

Comment: queue names are stored in .env files

Comment: How are the queues stored in the .env file, can you give an example? How are you switching between them?

Comment: @Reduxx
updated my question. please check

Answer (score 2):

```php
// config/queue.php
'rabbitmq_durable' => [
    'driver' => 'rabbitmq',
    // ...
    'queue_params' => [
        'passive' => false,
        'durable' => true,
        'exclusive' => false,
        'auto_delete' => false,
    ],
    // ...
],
'rabbitmq_not_durable' => [
    'driver' => 'rabbitmq',
    // ...
    'queue_params' => [
        'passive' => false,
        'durable' => false,
        'exclusive' => false,
        'auto_delete' => false,
    ],
    // ...
]
```

**Laravel 5.1**

To use different configs and different connections on Laravel 5.1 you have to use the `Queue` fascade:

```php
Queue::connection('rabbitmq_durable')->pushOn('queue_1', TestJob::class);
Queue::connection('rabbitmq_not_durable')->pushOn('queue_6', TestJob::class);
```

**Laravel 5.2+**

To use different configs and different connections on Laravel 5.2 and onwards you can use the `onConnection()` method like so:

```php
TestJob::dispatch()->onQueue('queue_one')->onConnection('rabbitmq_durable');
TestJob::dispatch()->onQueue('queue_six')->onConnection('rabbitmq_not_durable');
```

Comment: I am not sure this will work, because we have only one key for "rabbitmq" in config/queue.php .
Also how framework will get to know about connections other than "rabbitmq" i.q "rabbitmq_queue_1", "rabbitmq_queue_2"

Comment: you need to add addtional keys, laravel looks automatically trough each key and searches for the `'queue'` and decides which connection to use based upon the found queue. If it can't find it, it will fall back to the default connection

Comment: you mean laravel searches for 'queue' i.e 'queue' => env('QUEUE_ONE') in our case and while dispatching a jon on this queue it will use rabbitmq_queue_1 connection ?

Comment: Yes, this is what i meant :)

Comment: Have you tried it ? Didn't work on my side, again, durable queue created

Comment: It worked like a year back and I thought it would also do in 5.1, but I checked just  that even the method on the queueable-Trait `onConnection()` was introduced in 5.2 :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198308/discussion-between-reduxx-and-jake-conner).